# Convert amazon aws co-ordinates

Tags: python

How to convert the co-ordinates of bounding box returned by amazon aws face detect into open cv co-ordinates? As amazon aws just returns the bounding box co-ordinates not the image with box made around its face.

```
{u'BoundingBox': {u'Height': 0.45597776770591736,
                  u'Left': 0.16144350171089172,
                  u'Top': 0.21130676567554474,
                  u'Width': 0.5840455889701843},}
```

Suppose these are the bounding box co-ordinates of a image.
Can Amazon aws can draw box around face ?
if yes where can i get the python code?

Answer (score 1):

download the recognized image and do the following with opencv

```
 widtho = 717 #width of the given image
 heighto = 562 #height of the given image
 counter = 0
 facecount = 1
 s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
 bucket = s3.Bucket('rek')
 if __name__ == "__main__":
 #Choosing the file in s3 bucket
     photo = 'sl.jpg'
     bucket = 'rek'
 #Intilization of rekognition and performing detect_faces 
 client = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name='eu-west-1')
 response = client.detect_faces(
 Image={'S3Object': {'Bucket': bucket, 'Name': photo}}, Attributes=['ALL'])
 print('Detected faces for ' + photo)
 print('The faces are detected and labled from left to right')
 for faceDetail in response['FaceDetails']:
     print('Face Detected= ', i)
     #To mark a bounding box of the image using coordinates
     print('Bounding Box')
     bboxlen = len(faceDetail['BoundingBox'])
     print(bboxlen)
     width = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Width')
     height = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Height')
     left = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Left')
     top = faceDetail['BoundingBox'].get('Top')
     w = int(width * widtho)
     h = int(height * heighto)
     x = int(left * widtho)
     y = int(top * heighto)
     imagere = cv2.imread('imagename.jpg')#the image to append rects of all faces
     cv2.rectangle(imagere, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
     cv2.imwrite('imagename.jpg', imagere)
     facecount = facecount + 1
     abc[:] = []
```

Answer (score 0):

coordinates of bounding box:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('your image.png')
(h, w) = im.shape[:2]

box = {'Height': 0.45597776770591736,
                  'Left': 0.16144350171089172,
                  'Top': 0.21130676567554474,
                  'Width': 0.5840455889701843}

x,y,w,h = (box['Left'] * width, box['Top'] * height, box['Width'] * width, box['Height'] * height )
cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(200,0,0),2)
cv2.imshow('img',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```